# Can a negatively voted down answer be checked as the right one by the owner?

Tags: discussion, answers

This [question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31763/did-chipotle-give-away-free-burritos-on-feb-8-2016) is answered by the same OP and although it is negatively voted down, the owner has accepted his own answer! Can these type of answers be removed or deleted even though the owner has accepted it as the right answer?

Comment: Note: Since this meta-question was asked, that answer was deleted by a mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asker cannot be forced to accept a particular answer. They can self-answer and accept it. Self-accepts are not auto-bumped to the first in the list. Accepted answers are not necessarily the right answer.

Answers can be deleted if they don't answer the question or if they lack references.

Comment: But wont a first time user find it weird to find a negatively voted answer to have a tick mark next to it indicating that it is the appropriate answer?

Comment: Maybe they'll find it weird, but that's okay. There's a lot about this site that is weird. I think in this case it is obvious that it doesn't answer the question, even to a new user.

Comment: But such answers do exist without getting deleted as noted by Oddthinking using the query search mentioned below!

Comment: @pericles316: Be careful of survivorship bias. My query didn't return results that had been deleted. Presumably (I haven't checked) the answers on the open questions *do* address the question.

Comment: @Oddthinking-we need to have a check on that!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to the question, but it demonstrates the phenomena isn't a one-off:

- [Is a religious upbringing psychologically damaging to a child?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14335/is-a-religious-upbringing-psychologically-damaging-to-a-child/14337#14337) [Closed]
- [Does food aid cause famines?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13636/does-food-aid-cause-famines/19160#19160) [Self-Answer, competing with better one]
- [Alkaline diet afect cancer?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/20826/alkaline-diet-afect-cancer/20830#20830) [Duplicate, Self-Answer]
- [Have recommended calorie intakes increased significantly over the years, and if so is it due to food industry lobbying?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/11024/have-recommended-calorie-intakes-increased-significantly-over-the-years-and-if/26745#26745) [Self-Answer]
- [Does the combination of red wine and cheese cause bad dreams?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13643/does-the-combination-of-red-wine-and-cheese-cause-bad-dreams/16174#16174)
- [Can a person still fart after death?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/can-a-person-still-fart-after-death/6214#6214)
- [Was Shakespeare Marlowe? What does stylometry say?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8630/was-shakespeare-marlowe-what-does-stylometry-say/10412#10412) [Duplicate, self-answer, competing with better answers]

This data was generated with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/skeptics/query/435464/negatively-rated-accepted-answers).